# Empty app in Xamarin.Forms doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I made an empty template Xamarin.Forms in VS2017.

But it doesn's work. There is an error in MainPage.xaml.cs

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context    App5.Android, App5.iOS  C:\Users\gudiea\source\repos\App5\App5\App5\MainPage.xaml.cs    14  Active

Solutions with saving XAML and changing Custom Tool don't solve the problem.

Comment: Check that your MainPage.Xaml is set as Embedded Resource and that x:class is correct

Comment: Yes, it's Embedded Resource and x:class="App5.MainPage"

Comment: Restore NuGet Packages